# Error 1084 in AS3 (expecting identifier before dot)

Tags: actionscript-3, import, syntax-error, flash-cs4

I'm trying to access a function I've defined in an .as file I've imported. However, I keep getting error 1084. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code from my .fla file:

```
import .com.script.Script.as.*;
var a = new draggable();
```

Here is the code from my .as file:

```
package com.script{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Script {
        public var value:Number;

        private var max:Number;
        private var min:Number;

        function draggable() {
            min=bar_mc.y;
            max=bar_mc.height-Erhu_H3_btn.height;
             toErhu_H3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragHandle);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: when I do that, I get error 1180, call to a possibly undefined method draggable

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

your .fla file

```
import com.script.Draggable;
var a = new Draggable();
```

Here is the code from your .as file:

```
package com.script{

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Draggable{
        public var value:Number;

        private var max:Number;
        private var min:Number;

        public function Draggable(){
            min=bar_mc.y;
            max=bar_mc.height-Erhu_H3_btn.height;
            toErhu_H3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I do that, I get 2 'error 1172: Definition com.script:Draggable could not be found's and 'error 1180: call to a possibly undefined method Draggable'

Comment: I think your folder structure is incorrect.. !                

 ::follow this structure :: 

 :: create folder on your desktop name it "main":: 
 :: open main folder. create sub folder name it "com" :: 
 :: open com folder create sub folder name it "script" :: 

 :: (1) move your .fla file into main folder. ::    
 :: (2) move your .as file into script folder. ::

Comment: Sorry...I did as you suggested but I still get the same errors

Comment: Also, now I get error 5008 as well: the name of the definition "Draggable" does not reflect the location of this file